# No JS module 'tweener' found in search path, Gnome shell extension error on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, 20.10

Today I upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 20.10 and there is problem in one of the extensions in Gnome shell extensions.

The Extension [Panel OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/708/panel-osd/) giving the error "**No JS module 'tweener' found in search path**".

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `tweener` module has been moved to a new path, from `imports.ui.tweener` to `imports.tweener.tweener`. In the exention's [repository](https://gitlab.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-panel-osd), somebody already created a [merge request](https://gitlab.com/jenslody/gnome-shell-extension-panel-osd/-/merge_requests/30?commit_id=00890e56fc3c172369ccb3e06bb411386ae58bd5) to merge the necessary changes into the code, but the extension's developer hasn't merged it yet.

You can either wait until the developer does the change and puts out a new version of the extension, or - if you feel comfortable with it - change the import path in your local copy of the extension yourself. You can look up in the merge request what to change.